# Hashtag Hashtable

Tags: twitter, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashtag

Does anybody know if twitter a giant hashtable or hashmap?  If so is that where the whole "hashtag" colloquium came from?  I only ask because I feel this would be a fairly cool bit of trivia/society.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tag, and the octothorpe, 'number sign', or 'pound sign' is also known as the "hash symbol" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_symbol